# Loop through Mongo collections and execute query

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I'm trying to print the first document of each collection in my db. I have the following script:

```
var collectionNames = db.getCollectionNames();
for(var i = 0, len = collectionNames.length; i < len ; i++){
    db[collectionNames[i]].findOne() //find[0]
}
```

I don't see where is the error in my logic but this code only prints the first document from the latest collection

Answer (score 0):

Say that we have

```
> db.test1.save({item: 1})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.test1.save({item: 2})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.test1.save({item: 3})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.test2.save({item: 3})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.test2.save({item: 4})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
```

Then we can run:

```
>var docs = [];
>
> collectionNames.forEach(function(name){
... docs.push(db[name].findOne());
... });
```

Then we can print docs

```
> docs
[
        {
                "_id" : ObjectId("59fc9754cb24a8fbf29c6d5a"),
                "item" : 1
        },
        {
                "_id" : ObjectId("59fc9762cb24a8fbf29c6d5d"),
                "item" : 3
        }
]
```

The reason why `db[collectionNames[i]].findOne()` does not work in your example is that your doing nothing with the return value.